# What is best practice for running multiple Docker containers with code from different repos?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a web app that consists of multiple services (including a postgres db and redis), in multiple repos. Ideally I'd like to have all the Docker stuff in one repo, and build from there. However, I'm running into trouble since building the containers involves compiling code in other directories (or repositories), and you can't `ADD` from a different directory. Symlinking doesn't work either. And I don't want to pull from github into a container to avoid having ssh keys in the wild. Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? Or does each repo need its own Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its preferable to maintain one dockerfile for each project and keep each project independent of the others so that you can build each project separately.

However, if you cannot do that there can be some workarounds.

Your problem is that the docker build context is limiting the scope in which files can be accessed. I recommend that you wrap you docker build inside a script, that collects all dependencies and issues a build command. The script might look something like this:

```
mkdir build-dir

cp <path-to-file1> build-dir/file1
cp <path-to-file2> build-dirfile2
cp <path-to-Dockerfile> build-dir/Dockerfile
...
docker build -t image .
rm -rf build-dir
```

And the Dockerfile will be transparent as it assumes that all dependecies are in the build context.

```
FROM ...
ADD file1 file1
ADD file2 file2

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have two directories `parent/project1` and `parent/project2`, and have Dockerfile is at `parent/project1/`.

You can `ADD` both directories into a container.
If you are at `parent/`

```
$ docker build -f project1/Dockerfile .
```

Dockerfile is something like following.

```
ADD project1 /path/to/directory1
ADD project2 /path/to/directory2
```